# Linux file formating

Tags: linux, text-formatting

I have a file where character are in the type `abcd abcd abcd abcd` but my client wants them in the format as

```
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
```

Comment: I tried to add some formatting to your post, but please take a look and see if it's right.  See the [formatting help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) if needed.

Comment: Also, a more complete/thorough example of the contents would help Answerers give you something useful for your case. How should the transformation happen?

Comment: `sed 's/[[:blank:]]/\n/g' file`

Comment: Are the "fields" always separated by a space or tab? If a space and you want them separated by newlines instead you can use `tr` for this: `tr ' ' '\n' < filename

Answer (score 1):

Use the `tr` command to replace spaces with newlines.

```
tr ' ' '\n' < file.txt > newfile.txt
```

Comment: what if there two spaces between some items?

Comment: Then he should change the question to say that.

Answer (score 0):

If the delimeter is just a space the following command should work:

```
sed 's/[[:space:]]/\n/g' infilename > outfilename
```

otherwise use [[:blank:]] to also includ tabs, form feeds, newlines and carriage returens

If there are more spaces/blanks between the words, just use an asterix behind the [[:space:]] :

```
sed 's/[[:space:]]*/\n/g' infilename > outfilename
```